# storing image into database by using SpringMVC and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

following are the error messages when i m trying to store image into database by using `springMVC` and `Hiberrnate`.

Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to   required type 'java.sql.Blob' for property

I am using following set of code:-

1)In jsp

```
<html><body>
<form:form  action="submitPartner1.do" commandName="partnerindividual"  enctype="multipart/form-  data" >
 <input type="file" name="image" />
<form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

2)`Partner.java`

```
class Partner{

 Blob image;

 //getter and setter

 }
```

3)In controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitPartner1.do",method=RequestMethod.POST)

 public String save(@ModelAttribute("partnerindividual")Partner partnerindividual,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{

    Blob blob=null;
        try{
       byte[] contents = file.getBytes();
     blob = new SerialBlob(contents);
          partnerindividual.setImage(blob);
        //storing into database
        service.save(partnerindividual);
       }
       catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
       System.out.println(partindi);

return "becomeapartnerContinue";

}
}
```

4)
     In `spring_config.xml`

```
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error shows there is problem in conversion from file bytes to Blob.

Can you do changes to your save() method inside controller.

replace below line of code

```
blob = new SerialBlob(contents);

        with

blob = Hibernate.createBlob(contents);
```

Comment: what is session object is here  whether it is HttpSession or HibernateSession  object.......

Comment: Thanks for pointing it,createBlob(byte[]) is in Hibernate class,it's basically a final class.

Comment: It still causes the same problem                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [java.sql.Blob] for property 'image': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]